# logging result with rosunit in stdout

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi people!! I have some unitary tests in python made with rosunit. They work well but I'd like to log to stdout some test messages when I run:

> rosrun rosunit rosunit --text mytestfile.py

You can see below some tried alternatives but none of them worked. Any Idea? Thanks in advance :-):

> print "hi"

or

> rospy.loginfo("hi")

and even:

```
def setUp(self):
         logging.basicConfig( stream=sys.stdout )
         self.log=logging.getLogger( "TestDTW.output" )
         self.log.setLevel( logging.DEBUG )

def testXX(self):
         self.log.debug("hi")
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11501/logging-result-with-rosunit-in-stdout/) by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2982 on 2011-10-11

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There was a bug in rosunit where the --text option was not propagating properly.  I'm testing a fix in r15181.

You can get a patch from here:

https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/changeset/15181

Thanks for noting this issue.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2011-10-12**:
nice :-) Thanks.